# SqlDataReader Nao Fechado?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-basic-6

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class F_Contentor

Dim F_Topo As New Form2()
Dim F_Principal As New Form3()

Dim Prof_Ses_Nome As String
Dim Prof_Ses_Id As Integer

Const cs As String = "Data Source=D01PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Desinovar;Integrated Security=True"
Public con As New SqlConnection(cs)


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Prof_Ses_Nome = Login.prof_Ses_Nome.ToString()
    Prof_Ses_Id = Login.prof_Ses_ID
    Login.Close()
    F_Topo.TopLevel = False
    F_Principal.TopLevel = False
    Me.Painel_Topo.Controls.Add(F_Topo)
    Me.Painel_Main.Controls.Add(F_Principal)
    F_Topo.Show()
    F_Principal.Show()

    F_Topo.CB_Prof.Items.Add(Prof_Ses_Nome)
    F_Topo.CB_Prof.SelectedIndex = 0


End Sub

Public Sub Get_Turma()
    F_Topo.CB_Turma.Items.Clear()

    Using con
        Dim sql As String = "select Turma.Nome from Turma,Professores_Turma,Professores where Turma.Id_Turma = Professores_Turma.Id_Turma and Professores_Turma.Id_Professor = Professores.Id_Professor and Professores.Id_Professor ='" & Prof_Ses_Id & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        con.Open()

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read()
                F_Topo.CB_Turma.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
            End While
        Else
            ' Aqui faça o que quiser caso não tenha linha '
        End If

        dr.Close()
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub Get_Disciplinas()
    F_Topo.CB_Disciplina.Items.Clear()

    Using con
        Dim sql As String = "select Disciplinas.Nome from Disciplinas,Turma,Professores_Turma,Professores where Turma.Id_Turma = Professores_Turma.Id_Turma and Professores_Turma.Id_Professor = Professores.Id_Professor and Professores_Turma.Id_Disciplina = Disciplinas.Id_Disciplina  and Professores.Id_Professor ='" & Login.prof_Ses_ID & "' and Turma.Nome = '" & F_Topo.CB_Turma.SelectedItem & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        con.Open()

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read()
                F_Topo.CB_Disciplina.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
            End While
        Else
            ' Aqui faça o que quiser caso não tenha linha '
        End If

        dr.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
End Class
```

Tenho este código e quando o executo, ele diz me que a variável `dr` (SqlDataReader) não foi fechada. No fim de cada procedimento, fecho sempre a conexão da variável `dr`. Alguém Me consegue ajudar?

Comment: só para garantir, depois de `dr.Close()` põe `dr = Nothing`

Comment: Já ta. Não funciona :/

Comment: Estranho... o erro acontece em ambos os métodos? (`Get_Disciplinas()` e `Get_Turma()`) ?

Comment: Não. Apenas no Get_Turma(). Tenho outro colega com o mesmo erro..

Comment: depois do `While dr.Read()`, experimenta remover todo código dentro, e deixa apenas uma message box monstrando este conteúdo: `dr.Item(0).ToString`

funciona assim?

Comment: como nos comentários não consigo deixar código formatado, com responder com uma prévia solução... irei alterando na medida que fores dando o feedback

Comment: Ok. Ja funciona se remover todo o código dentro do while da Get_Turma().

Comment: Mas se puser este código: F_Topo.CB_Turma.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))

Já não funciona outra vez.

Comment: veja a minha resposta

Answer (score 0):

Como nos comentários não consigo deixar código formatado, com responder com uma prévia solução... irei alterando na medida que fores dando o feedback.

Primeiro... altere o método em questão para que fique assim:

```
Public Sub Get_Turma()
    F_Topo.CB_Turma.Items.Clear()

    using con
        Dim sql As String = "select Turma.Nome from Turma,Professores_Turma,Professores where Turma.Id_Turma = Professores_Turma.Id_Turma and Professores_Turma.Id_Professor = Professores.Id_Professor and Professores.Id_Professor ='" & Prof_Ses_Id & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As new SqlCommand(sql, con)
        con.Open()

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read()
                F_Topo.CB_Turma.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
            End While
        Else
            ' Aqui faça o que quiser caso não tenha linha '
        End If

        dr.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Tenta esta alteração

Comment: Obrigado. Quando puder testo o código :) (amanha)

Comment: A função "get_Turma()" ja funciona. O que não funciona agora é o get_disciplinas(). Actualizei a pergunta para o estado actual.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: A propriedade ConnectionString não foi inicializada.

Comment: Tenho ideia que o problema é que faco isto:

'Const cs As String = "Data Source=D01PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Desinovar;Integrated Security=True"'

'Public con As New SqlConnection(cs)'

Apenas uma vez globalmente em vez de fazer localmente em cada procedimento.